# Combine text/html file and render in webview

Tags: android, webview

I am working on project which need to display some information in web view, but the file is needed to be generated dynamically by combining two or more file `(html/text)` stored on internal storage, I am able combine files but not able to render it in `webview`. Please guide......

Here is the code

```
String html= CheckLocalHtml(context,"FileName.html")
webViewBasic.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///",html,"text/html", "utf-8", null);

public String CheckLocalHtml(Context context, String fName) {
    try {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).toString();
        File mFile, mDir;
        mDir = new File(root);
        if (mDir.exists()) {
            mFile = new File(mDir, fName);
            if (mFile.exists()) {
                StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mFile));
                String s="";
                while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    contentBuilder.append(s);
                }
                in.close();
                return contentBuilder.toString();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Page not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Directory not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ReadHTML","Error="+e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you tried, and explain in detail what "not able to render it in webview" means.

Answer (score 0):

I had figured it out.... saved file in storage and used webViewBasic.loadUrl("file:///" + file.getAbsolutePath());